# Не запускается .exe файл VS

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Написал программу , используя графическую библиотеку **SDL** на **Visual Studio**. Смог собрать и запустить программу через **Visual Studio**, но при запуске напрямую через созданный экзешник (в папке **Debug**, **Release**) программа запускает окно , а затем закрывается. Компилировал с конфигурациями **Debug** и **Release** на **x86** , ставил разные значения в библиотеке времени выполнения(**/MD** , **/MT**) ничего не помогает. Так же добавил папку с программой в исключения антивируса.
Прочитал в интернете про какие-то манифесты для развертывания , но думаю не в них дело.
Пишу на языке c++.

Ошибка оказалась в этой строке:

```
TTF_Font * gFont = TTF_OpenFont("16_true_type_fonts/lazy.ttf", 28);
```

Через VS там был какой то адрес , а при запуске через exe-файл в этой переменной NULL

Comment: Нужно, похоже, установить Visual C++ Redistributable Runtimes. Типа отсюда (не проверял) - https://www.comss.ru/page.php?id=6271

Comment: Вам следует отладить свою программу. @Majestio Он устанавливается совместно со студией. И если бы в нем была проблема, то даже окна бы не было.

Comment: Ошибка оказалась в этой строке:
TTF_Font * gFont = TTF_OpenFont("16_true_type_fonts/lazy.ttf", 28);
Через VS там был какой то адрес , а при запуске через exe-файл в этой переменной NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка была в том, что exe-файл не знал где искать файл со шрифтами , a VS знал.
Я добавил папку со шрифтами в папку из которой запускал exe-файл и все заработало.